# Gephi - Weight on nodes starting from edge list

Tags: graph, gephi

I have an edge list which contains two different weights, one for edges and one for nodes, e.g.

```
Source Target Edge_weights Node_weight
1       2     0.4          5
1       3     0.2          5
2       1     0.4          3
2       4     0.1          3
```

etc..

I can import this fine in Gephi, but cannot make the different node look different based on their node weight. If I go to the ranking tab in the overview pane I can rank nodes based on the different degrees, but not on   the Node_weight. Instead, I am allowed to rank edges this way.

Is there any simple way to make my node change appearence (preferably grow proportionally) based on the 4th column of my edge list file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by generating a Node List to go with my Edge List, reporting Node_weight and then using it to rank my nodes.